# How to refactor this code with data frame from CSV?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I wrote a code that works, but it was like a McGwyver code, and I'm not satisfied. How can I refactor it more professionally?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("DB_Teste.csv", sep=(";"))

sales_by_seller = df.groupby('Vendedor')['Valor'].sum()

vendas_por_vendedor = str(sales_by_seller).split('Vendedor ')

venda_separada = []
cont = 0

for venda in vendas_por_vendedor:
  if cont != 0:
    venda_separada.append(str(venda).split())
  cont += 1

ordem_vendedores = []

for i in venda_separada:
  novo_i = str(i).split(" ")
  vendedor = novo_i[0]
  if vendedor == ['Vendedor']:
    pass
  else:
    if vendedor[3] not in '0123456789':
      ordem_vendedores.append(vendedor[2])
    else:
      ordem_vendedores.append(vendedor[2] + vendedor[3])


print("\nTabela que sumarize o valor vendido por cada vendedor, ordenando do maior para o menor: ")
lista_de_somas = []
for x in range(len(ordem_vendedores)):

    numeros = re.findall(r'\d+', sales_by_seller[x])
    numeros_float = list(map(float, numeros))

    soma = sum(numeros_float)

    lista_de_somas.append(soma)

nova_lista = list(zip(ordem_vendedores, lista_de_somas))
nova_lista.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for i, j in nova_lista:
  print(f'Vendedor {i} = R$ {j:.2f}')
```

The output must be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHmUC.png)

And the CSV input file is:
[CSV File With Data os Sales Result by Salespeople](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xptucnu5dLUqX_uRncRJNY_Nf_8zKpnL/view?usp=sharing)

A cleaner code. Because it's already working.

Comment: first use 4 spaces for indentations. Or you some tools to format code.

Comment: instead of `==` you can use `!=` without `pass` and `else`

Comment: I think this is question rather for similar portal [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: use english names for variables. More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)